# React Formik Form - Remember the values of fields when user switches the form tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, formik

I am using Formik forms with my react application. I have multiple tabs (each tab content is a separate component) and each tab is containing a form. When I switch from one tab to another my field data gets lost. (Happening because the component reloads again and sets the initial value which is  ''). I wanted to retain the value of all the forms of all the tabs and save them all at once. Lets say user enters details for some form fields in tab1 form, goes to tab2, fills out the form details, he should be able to come back to tab 1 and start from the point where he left off (values he entered earlier should remain there).

One solution could be to use wizard but that will enforce user to fill up the forms in steps like 1 > 2 > 3 > ... which is not ideal in my case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you found a solution to this one?